# Getting column_name different in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have two following tables with similar structure with id1 and id2 as unique:

```
             Table1
id1    id2   amt1    amt2    id3
1A      1     12      14     12A
2A      4     23      35     34V
3A      8     45      23     13D
.................................

            Table2
id1    id2   amt1    amt2    id3
1A      1     12      27     12A
2A      4     67      35     34D
3A      8     45      23     13D


.................................
```

So id1 and id2 are unique here so what i wanted to create a query to which tells me for which id which amt is not matching so i made i simple script like this:

```
select T.id1,T.id2,
T.amt1,      P.amt1,
T.amt2,      P.amt2,
T.id3,       P.id3
from 
Table1 T,
Table2 P
where 
T.id1=P.id1
T.id2=P.id2
(
nvl(T.amt1 ,0)-nvl(P.amt1 ,0)<>0 OR      --used nvl to check if one table has null for other tables's number
nvl(T.amt2 ,0)-nvl(P.amt2 ,0)<>0 OR
T.id3  <>P.id3  
);
```

This gives me the difference but i becomes difficult to analyze on large tables and suppose i had lot of columns and amounts and lot of differences i want to see the output in a format shown below:
Suppose i am looking for differences in `Table1`

```
id1  id2  difference in column
1A    1       amt2
2A    4       amt1,id3
```

Can anybody show what query can generate output like as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following query and test:

```
select * from (select T.id1,T.id2,
T.amt1,      P.amt1,
T.amt2,      P.amt2,
T.id3,       P.id3
decode(nvl(T.amt1 ,0)-nvl(P.amt1 ,0),0,'','amt1')||' '||decode(nvl(T.amt2 ,0)-nvl(P.amt2 ,0),0,'','amt2')||' '||decode(nvl(T.id3 ,0),nvl(P.id3 ,0),'','ID3') difference_in_col
from 
Table1 T,
Table2 P
where 
T.id1=P.id1
and T.id2=P.id2
) where difference_in_col is not null;
```

This is assuming that you have only limited known number of columns to be checked.

if not then you will have to go for a procedure script to populate a table or show you the result in dbms_output.

that will have to be made too dynamic. depends on requirement

Comment: id3 is varchar2 so nvl on that will not work so how can i get varchar2 or char type datatypes to show up?

Answer (score 1):

How about the following hideous beast of convoluted (and untested) SQL?

```
select id1
      ,id2
      ,decode(a.amt1, b.amt1, null, 'amt1,') ||
       decode(a.amt2, b.amt2, null, 'amt2,') || 
       decode(a.id3,  b.id3,  null, 'id3,') as difference_in_column
  from table1 a
  join table2 b using(id1, id2)
 where decode(a.amt1, b.amt1, 1, 0) = 0
    or decode(a.amt2, b.amt2, 1, 0) = 0
    or decode(a.id3,  b.id3,  1, 0) = 0;
```

Note 1. I used the decode() construct because it treats null as equal to null.

Note 2. You can change to `FULL OUTER JOIN` if you also want to find rows in table1 that does not exist in table2 or vice verca.

Note 3. I haven't removed the trailing comma in the list.

Comment: id3 is varchar2 so i think this will not work so how can i get varchar2 or char type columns to show up?

Comment: @Auguster, Which part do you mean? As long as the data type is the same in both tables decode works.